# cross account per VPC access

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-controls, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc, vpc

All developers and testers are in the development account(account d). the production and testing environments are another account (account x) however in two different VPC's - VPC-P and VPC-T. How do I limit access to testers into the VPC-P while developers enjoying Access to VPC-P only. There are also other VPC's in Account X. And developers/testers need not have access to other stuff in the Account X.

Comment: What do you mean by "limit access into the VPC"? How do your staff connect to AWS resources -- is it across the internet, or do you have Direct Connect that links the VPCs to your corporate network? Can they currently access _all_ VPCs?

Comment: We dont want dev's to see test VPC and vice versa. Direct Connect. But Dev's can get Dev and Prod VPC.

Comment: I re-read it. Limit access as in the AWS Console. Stop each other from changing each other's environments.

Comment: So you merely wish to "Stop each other from changing each other's environments" within the AWS console? For example, The "Dev" group can change the "Dev VPC", but not change anything about the "Prod VPC"? Nothing to do with actually accessing resources within the various VPCs themselves?

Comment: Is that even the right approach? We tend to put all user's in a separate account and have different accounts for environments. I didn't build it that way, its how the estate was when I took over.

Comment: Separate accounts for Dev and Prod is a recommended approach to ensure no interference between the two.

Comment: Sounds good for a future plan. How do I go about limiting VPC access to cross account users on the AWS console for now?

Comment: By default, users cannot do anything to resources in another AWS Account. If VPC-A belongs to Account-A, then it is only accessible to IAM Users defined in Account-A. Users in Account-B would _not_ have access to view/change/modify settings on VPC-A. In addition, users within an account have no permissions unless specifically granted. Your question only mentions one account. If you are now asking about a multi-account scenario, please update your question appropriately.

Comment: All user's are coming out of account-A. VPC's are in account-X. As per in question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your situation is:

Account-D contains:

- IAM Users for developers and testers

Account-X contains:

- VPC-P
- VPC-T

You want to allow 'testers' in Account-D to modify the settings on VPC-T.

You want to allow 'developers' in Account-D to modify the settings on VPC-P.

This does not appear to be possible. According to [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html), only some actions can accept a VPC as a condition, such as:

- `ec2:CreateVpcPeeringConnection`
- `ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission`
- `ec2:CreateRoute`

Commands like `CreateSubnet` and `DeleteSubnet` do not allow any conditions.

Therefore, it would not be possible to restrict many VPC-related permissions to operate only on a specific VPC.

Given that you are dealing with testers and developers, I would **recommend using separate AWS Accounts for each environment**. Have one Account for Developers, where IAM Users and VPCs are defined. Have a separate AWS Account for Testers to ensure that they have no access into the Developers account. This creates a clean separation of environments.

Comment: In the video on https://aws.amazon.com/answers/aws-landing-zone/. It tells us how we can limit access by keeping user's in one account. There must someway or feature in landing zone we dont see perhaps? Can we use tags on VPC's specified while assuming role from the account D and specify the tag? maybe it works only on roles?

Comment: Yes and No. [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html) does show many commands that can be limited by Tag, but not everything. You should check the list for what commands you would want to allow them to use.